# Prevent progressive jpeg from loading completely

Tags: jpeg, progressive

So, let's say I have a large version of an image that gets displayed only as a thumbnail. Would it be possible to avoid having a separate file for the thumbnail by using a progressive jpeg, stopping its loading when a certain number of scans have been reached, and continue loading only when the user chooses to open it in full?

If so, how can the loading of the image be controlled?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have control of the decoder, just trim the file to only include the first scan and you'll get just the DC values (1/8 size) for your image.

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. How do you mean trim the file? Could expand your comment into a possible answer?

Comment: It seems that I have been taking this from the wrong direction: the server should stop sending the data, not the client receiving. Still not sure how to accomplish it though.

Comment: Please see my answer below, I have updated it to include a client side and server side solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

## 1. Client-side heavy

**Prerequisite**

- the image server has to support the [range HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)

  - eg. `Range: bytes=0-1024` means you are requesting only the first 1024 bytes
- you **have to know in advance** how many bytes you want to request

  - you can say 1/8th of full size, if you push that value from server side
  - so the exact byte number should be known in the client side
- if the `Range` is not valid or not supported, then the server will return the whole image, which is a good natural "fallback"

**Cross domain requests**: if html and images are on different domains

- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "range"` has to be set

Apache `.htaccess` example **on image server**:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "range"
</IfModule>
```

- If the browser fails to make the request due to improper `CROS` settings, the code falls back to set the `data-src` attribute to the `src` attribute

**Overview**

1. request image with an `AJAX` request

   - set `Range` header of `AJAX` request to how many bytes you want to get back
   - set the `mimeType` to plaintext (so we can base64 encode it later)
2. Base64 encode data and set it to image's src attribute (`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...">`)

   - beware for larger images this can be quite heavy on the client
3. If setting the src attribute fails for whatever reason (eg. improper `CROS` settings), then fall back to set the `data-src` attribute to the `src` attribute

**The code**

This is built on gaetanoM's awesome answer here: [Get Image using jQuery.ajax() and decode it to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124701/get-image-using-jquery-ajax-and-decode-it-to-base64)

```js
// for each img, which has data-src and data-bytes attributes
$('img[data-src][data-bytes]').each(function(i,e){
 $.ajax({
     url: $(e).data('src'), // url of image
     type: 'GET',
     headers: {
      'Range':'bytes=0-'+$(e).data('bytes') // Range header, eg. Range: bytes=0-1024
     },
     mimeType: "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"
 }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     $(e).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64encode(data)); // on success we set the base64 encoded data to the image's src attribute
 }).always(function(){
     // if setting the src failed for whatever reason, we fall back to set the data-src attribute to src attribute
     if(!$(e).attr('src'))
         $(e).attr('src', $(e).data('src'));
 });
});

function base64encode(str) {
    var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;
    while (i < len) {
        c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
        if (i == len) {
            out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
            out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
            out += "==";
            break;
        }
        c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        if (i == len) {
            out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
            out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
            out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
            out += "=";
            break;
        }
        c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
        out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
        out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
        out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
    }
    return out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- total filesize is 35 933 bytes -->
<img data-src="http://shoepimper.com/doklist.com-logo.jpg" data-bytes="1900">
<img data-src="http://shoepimper.com/doklist.com-logo.jpg" data-bytes="2500">
<img data-src="http://shoepimper.com/doklist.com-logo.jpg" data-bytes="5600">

<!-- if data-bytes are erroneous the server will return the whole image -->
<img data-src="http://shoepimper.com/doklist.com-logo.jpg" data-bytes="error">
<!-- if CROS fails, then it falls back to set the data-src attribute to the src attribute -->
<img data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOPRf.jpg" data-bytes="error">
```

## 2. Server-side heavy

Ellaborating on ProgressiveMonkey's comment, you can easily trim the image data with php, or any other server side programming language.

**Overview**

- **server side**: trim the image data based on an url parameter

  - if you want to know exactly where the first scan ends, please read this wonderful answer: [How many bytes are needed for a complete thumbnail of a progressive JPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919839/how-many-bytes-are-needed-for-a-complete-thumbnail-of-a-progressive-jpeg)
- **client side**: change that url parameter as you wish

**Server-side code**

```
<?php
    $div = isset($_GET['div']) && intval($_GET['div'])>1 ? intval($_GET['div']) : 1; // what fraction of the image shall we return
    $img = 'doklist.com-logo.jpg';
    $size = round(filesize($img) / $div); // calculating the size in bytes what we return

    // setting the headers
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Length: $size");

    $fp = fopen($img, 'r');
        echo fread($fp, $size); // returning the necessary amount of bytes
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Examples**

Please see here an example of one of our site's logo ([Doklist.com](https://www.doklist.com))

Please feel free to play along with this url's `div` parameter (also please note that my test server may not handle the increased traffic well):
http://shoepimper.com/progressive-thumb.php?div=14

Reading just **1/24th** of the filesize and returning it as a whole image: 
`<img src="http://shoepimper.com/progressive-thumb.php?div=24">`
[image]

Reading **1/14th** of the image:
`<img src="http://shoepimper.com/progressive-thumb.php?div=14">`
[image]

Reading **1/6th** of the image:
`<img src="http://shoepimper.com/progressive-thumb.php?div=6">`
[image]

Reading the **whole** image (1/1th)
`<img src="http://shoepimper.com/progressive-thumb.php?div=1">`
[image]

If you need help to determine whether the image is progressively encoded or not, then use this: http://codepen.io/sergejmueller/full/GJKwv

If you don't have direct access to the images, then you should use a proxy, meaning the structure of the code itself doesn't really change, you just "fopening" a remote file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible. You would just need to modify a decoder to do it.

You can control the loading as long as you have access to the data stream.